# print a specific folder name from path on python

Tags: python-2.7

```
import os

path = 'D:/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.txt'

folders=[]

while 1:
    path,filename=os.path.split(path)

    if filename!="":
        folders.append(filename)
    else:
        if path!="":
            folders.append(path)
            print folders

        break
```

how to print only one folder name from path? for example print folder2 only or print folder1 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the list index, where the first element in your list (`file.txt`) is the element with index `0`.

For example:

```
print folders[1]
```

Output:

```
folder3
```

Likewise, `print folders[4]` will output `D:/`.